# Exporting Test Collections in Postman Jetpack

Tags: postman

I have a collection of tests in Postman.  I'd like to backup this collection.

Is there a way to export the collection as a JSON or text file?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you open Postman and look at the sidebar on the left, then hover over the name of the collection there five options: 'Add Folder', 'Edit Collection', 'Duplicate Collection', 'Share Collection', and 'Delete Collection'. 
Select the 'Share Collection' option and from there you will see a 'Download' button that will allow you to export your collection as the JSON file.

Comment: This no longer works as they've locked postman down and you have to give them your data in order to export it.

Comment: It works if you have an account. The Team part is locked down, but the private collections together with link sharing is working. At least it is working for me and i have not accepted any 30 day trial or the sort.

Answer (score 74):

The answers above work well if you only want to export one collection.

If you have *many* collections and want to export them all, there's a better way:

Wrench icon (top-right) -> Settings -> Data tab -> Export Data -> Download

This will create a single json file with all your collections.

Comment: Thank you kind sir. For some reason i struggled to find that wrench icon and the data tab. Given I am a newbie but this helped me migrate my stuff to another pro account. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. This still seems to be the way to go in 2018.

Answer (score 30):

I took pictures to help people more.

### Export one collection

The first way is by clicking on ... button and then clicking on export (or share if make sense)
 [image: ...]

The other way is to click on > button and then clicking on download collection

[image: >]

Both will give you your data in JSON format which you can use to import on another postman too.

### Update (Export all collections as Cristi Diaconescu has mentioned)

[image: settings]

and then Data tab> download

[image: Data tab>Download]

Answer (score 5):

Postman let's you export collections in a JSON file. Click on the "Share" button in the sidebar and then click "Download" in the modal that opens up.

Comment: I am assuming this is under My Name -> My Collections -> Download.  When I download the collection, I get a message saying the collection has been downloaded - but where is the file stored?

Comment: No. Use the sidebar share icon. Hovering over the collection name will show the share button, clicking on that will show this screen: http://getpostman.com/img/docs/source/23.png

Comment: I am hovering over this http://postimg.org/image/61ir174vl/.  But nothing comes up

Comment: I'm seeing a "..." button to the right of the collection name. When I click this I see the Share option.

Answer (score 2):

Best way which I used, Create a login on postman and whenever You do login on another computer login with the same account, You will get all the data.

Otherwise, Export the data into Json format from setting->data.
And the same json can be used for import.

Answer (score 0):

The new version of Postman (6.7.4) no longer has this in the gear icon, it's under the wrench icon in the top bar, Settings / Data.