# Backup Postman Configuration to file - environment and settings

Tags: postman

How do you backup all the configuration including environments, globals and collections to a file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39530925/797243) for my question - although it didn't answer the original question over there.

Basically you can create a .json export file like this:

```
Settings -> Data tab -> Export Data -> Download
```

Comment: No such option exists

Answer (score 12):

#### Download all data (including collections, globals, etc.)

Export using the Postman application:

```
Settings -> Data tab -> Export Data -> Download
```

[image]

---

#### Download collections

Download each collection from the Postman application: Click on the triple dots and select `Export`

[image]

---

#### Backup integrations

You can set up an auto integration to back up your collections (to Github, etc.):

Login into the [website](http://getpostman.com) and select your workspace, then go under the `integrations` tab and add API integration.

[image]

If you want to set up integrations to other software (e.g. Bitbucket) that isn't available, you can achieve by using the custom webhook. For more details, you can read this official [blog post](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman_pro/integrations/custom_webhooks/#backup-collections).

The related official [blog post](https://blog.getpostman.com/2017/03/10/backup-and-sync-your-postman-collections-on-github/) for backup options.

Comment: The option doesn't exist